# cronjob not running daily

Tags: cron, debian-wheezy, rsyslog

I am a linux newbie. With that said I need a cronjob to compress some syslog files after 48 hours to keep the size manageable. 
These files are currently located in /syslog - a disk I added to handle the volume. 
I had asked a previous question to handle this but here I am after that and the cronjob did not run. It should have run hours ago. 
I believe the job was set to run at 01:00:00 daily. 
Here is my current crontab.

```
root@mysyslogserver:/etc# more crontab
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
0 1 * * * /bin/gzip /syslog/*-$(/bin/date --date='2 days ago' +%F)
```

I am wondering if the formatting is what is messing me up?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This should best be handled by `logrotate`.

Comment: looking at that crontab there's no user listed for the last cron job, is that what you wanted in there?  Did you add the job via crontab -e as root?

Comment: @Sven - had considered this, however I was having difficulty using log rotate with files that contained dates in them, as my syslogs do. I could compress them and then add a date, but I already have them created by date with the date in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sven said, the better solution would be to use `logrotate` or similar tools designed for this.

However, for sake of explaining there are two problems.
You did not specify a user as which the cron should run.

And secondly the `%F` part.
You need to escape the %, as described in `man 5 crontab`:

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
>   run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or %
>   character, will be executed  by /bin/sh  or  by  the  shell specified
>   in the SHELL variable of the cronfile.  Percent-signs (%) in the
>   command, unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into
>   newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the
>   command as standard input.

So, this:

```
 0 1 * * * root /bin/gzip /syslog/*-$(/bin/date --date='2 days ago' +\%F)
```

Should work.

Comment: ok, with that in mind, I am going through the man for logrotate
I find that I can make a script from the samples, but I don't understand hwo to utilize the delaycompress after I use compress. 
what value do I append to it? -2? Keeping in mind I want 2 days of uncompressed files.

Comment: `delaycompress` does not take any argument. With it you end up with having the current log and $yesterday uncompressed (which is the behavior you want, no?). But I wouldn't do that anyway, why not compress it? You can look at them with `zless` without decompressing (or any recent version of `less` will auto-detect it for you too).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add an user for running that job, correct it:

`0 1 * * * root /bin/gzip /syslog/*-$(/bin/date --date='2 days ago' +%F)`

Comment: As I've explained in my answer that is only half the solution.